# How to blit rectangle on mouse position when rectangle collide with other rectangle using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I trying to make a game menu. I made a settings button on the screen and I want to blit rectangle on mouse position but i cant blit this ractangle and don't know why its doesn't work

A game loop here:

```
import pygame
from sys import exit

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))

game_active = 0
rect_x,rect_y = (20,20)


settings_button_motion = pygame.image.load('Path of file').convert_alpha()
settings_button_motion_rect = settings_button_motion.get_rect(topleft = (rect_x,rect_y))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif game_active == 0:
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if settings_button_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    rect_x,rect_y = event.pos
                    screen.blit(settings_button_motion, settings_button_motion_rect)
```

I want to `blit` rectangle correctly, `rect_x` and `rect_y` are changing coordinates correctly but it doesn't `blit` on screen